# SQL Server mirroring / failover alternative

Tags: sql-server, mirroring, high-availability, failover

I am looking at building at reliable database with Microsoft SQL Server, with mirroring and automatic failover. The SQL Server here is standard version, not enterprise one so High Availability Solutions is not supported.

Just wonder if there is any third-party tool we can use as an alternative?

It's SQL Server 2014 I'm using.

Comment: Do you think any 3rd party tool that does this is going to be cheaper than upgrading to SQL Server Enterprise edition?

Comment: @GreenstoneWalker Is there any?

Comment: What are your requirements? Have you considered  transactional replication or logshipping since you are on standard edition ?

Comment: @Kin for this I'm hoping to have a secondary server up running for automatic failover if the primary one is down in case, without changing the connection details from my website.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand, you state you are going to use mirroring, in standard it is still available so why can't you use that?  Or is the question that is there anything else available?

You can also use Failover clustering in standard edition, the limit is you can only use 2 nodes but I don't see that as an issue for your request.

Also, if you are using any virtualization technology (VMware, Hyper-V etc) there may be options that you can speak to your virtualization about which are edition (not to mention software) agnostic.

Mat